# C# BeginReceiveFrom is giving me an error

Tags: c#, sockets

I need a program to listen to several machines that send out some UDP on their status. I cut and pasted bits from a chat program and got things working but on startup I get an error "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because the queue was full". If I Ok the error then all works well. In the code below if I remove the While(true) I do not get the error but I only get one entry. I thought but may be wrong that the callback will just keep running and everytime it gets data will send it to be dealt with. This is I believe where my problem is but I cannot work out how to fix it so how do I keep receiving data without polling the socket?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
   {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        //We are using UDP sockets
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        //Assign the any IP of the machine and listen on port number 701
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 701);

        //Bind this address to the server
        serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);

        IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        //The epSender identifies the incoming clients
        EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;


        while (true)
        {

            //Start receiving data
            serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), epSender);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSServerUDP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for `OnReceive` if possible [as a edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25769099/edit).

Comment: Remove the dreadful CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls assignment.  Remove the fundamentally wrong while(true) loop.  You'll now have much better odds writing correct code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `BeginReceiveFrom` in a loop. Put it back by itself. What you need to do is put another `BeginReceiveFrom` inside the `OnReceive` function and that will grab the next set of data.